# Simplifying $(A\implies B)\implies(A\implies C)$

Tags: logic

> Simplify $(A\implies B)\implies(A\implies C)$ as much as possible.

I've converted the implications so that $$(\neg A\vee B)\implies(\neg A\vee C)$$ and then $$\neg(\neg A\vee B)\vee(\neg A\vee C)$$ but after that I don't know what more I can do. I've tried applying De Morgan in a hope to reduce it to only one $A$, but I keep going in circles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go on with De Morgan laws you get
$$
(A\land \lnot B)\lor(\lnot A\lor C)
$$
that can be reordered as
$$
\bigl((A\land \lnot B)\lor\lnot A\bigr)\lor C
$$
Apply distributivity to the expression $(A\land \lnot B)\lor\lnot A$, that gives $(A\lor\lnot A)\land(\lnot B\lor\lnot A)$; the first term can be removed, being true, so we remain with
$$
(\lnot B\lor\lnot A)\lor C
$$
and, again with De Morgan, we get $(A\land B)\Rightarrow C$